# How can I pull webpage data into my DataFrame by referencing a specific HTML class or id using pandas read_html?

Tags: python, html, pandas, beautifulsoup, datareader

I'm trying to pull the data from the table at [this site](https://www.biopharmcatalyst.com/biotech-stocks/company-pipeline-database#marketCap=mid%7Cstages=approved,crl) and save it in a CSV with the column 'ticker' included. Right now my code is this:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.biopharmcatalyst.com/biotech-stocks/company-pipeline-database#marketCap=mid|stages=approved,crl'
html = requests.get(url).content
df_list = pd.read_html(html)
df = df_list[0]
print (df)
df.to_csv('my data.csv')
```

and it results in a file that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heCAO.png).

I want to have the 'ticker' column in my CSV file with the corresponding ticker listed for each company. The ticker is in the HTML [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TkBs.png) (class="ticker--small"). The output should look like [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6mke.png)

I'm totally stuck on this. I've tried doing it in BeautifulSoup too but I can't get it working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to associate each ticker with the table you have got. Pandas read html can't be used for all cases. As you said you need Beautiful Soup kind of library to parse the html and then build an table using it

Comment: How would you suggest I do that? The post below doesn't solve it in BeautifulSoup.

Comment: According to the terms of use of the site: "scraping on data is not permitted as per the Terms of Use." And, unfortunately, it seems that the site intentionally makes it difficult to do the simple web scraping. You may be able to use beautifulsoup to pull all elements with `<div class="filter-table__row js-tr">` one at a time

Comment: I saw that class but wasn't sure how to use it, how would you incorporate it into ewwink's code in the comment below?

Answer (score 0):

it has multiple table, use BeautifulSoup to extract and do loop to write the csv.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests, lxml
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.biopharmcatalyst.com/biotech-stocks/company-pipeline-database#marketCap=mid|stages=approved,crl'
html = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
tables = soup.findAll('table')

for table in tables:
    df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
    with open('my_data.csv', 'a+') as f:
      df.to_csv(f)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately, this yields the same result as I already have, there is no column in the CSV file for ticker or company name.

Comment: How would I do that?